# PHP MySQL, get next key

Tags: mysql, phpmailer, php

I'm very new to PHP/MySQL.

I have a form that submits data into the following categories of my MySQL database:

DATE_INIT, PARTNO, QTY

I also have a column titled "ECRNUM" that is my primary key and auto-increments. 
After the data is placed in the database, I have a phpmailer that needs to include the primary key (ECRNUM) in the subject line. I'm trying to figure out how I can get the primary key of the data that was just put into the database. Can someone help? If its a SQL query, can someone guide me in the right direction of what syntax to use?

FYI
I used PDO to input the data:

```
$sqlx = "INSERT INTO opendpu (DATE_INIT, PARTNO, QTY) VALUES (:datex, :partno, :qty)";
 $statement = $db->prepare($sqlx);
$params = array(
      ":datex" => $datex,
      ":partno" => $partno,
      ":qty" => $qty
      );

$statement->execute($params) or die(print_r($statement->errorInfo(), true));
$db = null;

}
  catch ( PDOException $exception )
{
  echo "PDO error :" . $exception->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Syntax:

```
public string PDO::lastInsertId ([ string $name = NULL ] )
```

For example with a DB handler of `$dbh`:

```
print $dbh->lastInsertId();
```

Comment: If i wanted to set a specific variable ($ecr) to that primary key value would i use: $ecr = print $sqlx->lastInsertId("ECRNUM");

Comment: No print statement but other than that yes. I just included the print example as it was the simplest example I could think of so you could see and verify the output.